# How to fill the right information in RTC2GIT Config file

Tags: azure-devops, rational-team-concert

I am migrating From RTC to azure devops, so I am trying to migrate my source code to git first.
I'm using [rtc2git repository](https://github.com/rtcTo/rtc2git) on github.
**The problem is: I am not able to fill the information required in the configuration file.**
So if anyone can help me by explaining what are they.

***Here is the configuration file contents:***

```
[General]
Repo=C:\Users\QusaiAtoon\workspace
User=user
Password=pass
GIT-Reponame = repositoryForRTCMigration.git
WorkspaceName=C:\Users\QusaiAtoon\workspace
Directory = C:\Users\QusaiAtoon\MigrateHere
useExistingWorkspace = true

[Migration]
StreamToMigrate = ApplicationA
```